# Rare or Unique materials in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Are there items in the game that you can only ever get once and will need later on to craft that one thing or the like? I have recently dug into this game and find my inventory is filling up with all sorts of items for fear that I will throw out/dismantle or sell something I can not get back.

To that end I am looking for a list of items to hold on to for future use or confirmation that there is nothing to worry about, sell all of the stuff I have and stop being so poor cause I can get more later!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no materials that are one of a kind, however, some are a pain in the butt to get a regular amount of.

Honestly, once you get to the late game, you'll find so many swords and pieces of armour to sell that you should just hold onto any and all crafting materials you come across.

Comment: So keep the materials sell the gear and things balance out in the long run?

Comment: @James Yep. Most likely, you'll only end up using Witcher gear, so selling a sword isn't too bad if you decided you actually wanted to try it. However, if you're crafting something and find you're one short on something you sold previously and you have to treck to some godforsaken corner of the map to get the drop from the one enemy that drops it (looking at you, Arachas), you'll be wishing you'd have just waited for the extra gold to drop.